# Where does the NPM package come from?

Tags: npm

I have question about npm. When I writing 'npm install' npm packages are installing in folder 'node_modules'.

Where does the NPM package come from? Is it git repository?

Answer (score 2):

NPM (Node Package Manager) can install a node module (i.e., a package) from any number of locations.  In many cases, [npm-install](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install) installs all the packages listed in the `package.json` file associated with your application and by default stores them in your local [`node_modules` folder](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/folders).

If it reads the package to be installed from your `package.json`, then typically, the package is retrieved from https://registry.npmjs.org/.

However, you can install packages from git, other servers, or even a local NPM package that you create and name.

Comment: I meant to say registry.npmjs.org (Now updated).  When you use `npm install` it will make a request to registry.npmjs.org with the packages that you need as a parameter.  Take a look at https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install for more info.

Comment: how can i see consist (files)of npm package on registry.npmjs.org ?

Comment: Are you asking for a list of all available NPM packages?  That is a separate question from what you asked above.